# Sampradayas and Injunctions

Tags: scripture, gods, philosophy, sects, sampradaya

We know there are different *Sampradayas*(Sects) and sub sects and each have their own injunctions about the social life/interaction as well as devotional/spiritual/ritual interaction. Which among different *Sampradayas* have the most rigid rules?
Many a times I see people taking the cover of spiritual/divine/symbolic interpretation of scriptures as opposed to literal/physical interpretation, which *Sampradayas* lean more towards literal interpretation?